# Upload files not working in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am not able to upload files in codeigniter, and i am not getting any error, i am confused as to why this is happening and I also want to upload multiple attachments once i am done with this, but somehow i am not getting any errors while executing these codes, Is there any visible error or am i missing something? I have not uploaded any files before and this is my first attempt. I am attaching the MVC codes below:

My view form is :

```html
<!-- form start -->
<?php echo  form_open_multipart('exits/manager_add_absconding/'.$id,array('name'=>'addostcstevent','id'=>'addostcstevent','method'=>'post','autocomplete'=>'on','class'=>'form-horizontal'))?>
<?php echo form_hidden(array('id'=>$row->id,'action'=>$action));?>
<div class="box-body">

<input type="hidden" name="todays_date" readonly id="todays_date" value="<?php echo date('m/d/y');?>" class="form-control col-md-10" <?php if($USER->permissions[0] != 'all') { ?> readonly <?php } ?>>




<table>
<tr>
<td>
Name
</td>
<td>

      <select class="form-control" name="name">
            <?php 
   

            foreach($groups as $row)
            { 
   
              echo '<option  value="'.$row->firstname.'">'.$row->firstname.' '.$row->lastname.'</option>';
            }
            ?>
            </select>


</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Exit Type
</td>
<td>

<select class="form-control" id="security_question_1" name="exit_type">
        <option name="exit_type" value="" selected>Select a option</option>
  <option name="exit_type" value="Absconding">Absconding</option>

</select>




</td>
</tr>


<tr></tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label>Absconding Since</label>
</td>
<td>
<div class="date" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" data-date-viewmode="years">
<input placeholder="Absconding Since" class=" m-wrap col-md-8 form-control " id="enddt" type="text" name="abscondingsince" value="<?php if($row->requested_date!='') echo date("d-m-Y",$row->requested_date); ?>" required/>
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
<label>Date of contact via Phone</label>
</td>
<td>
<div class="date" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" data-date-viewmode="years">
<input placeholder="Date of contact via Phone" class=" m-wrap col-md-8 form-control " id="enddtt" type="text" name="dateofcontactviaphone" value="<?php if($row->requested_date!='') echo date("d-m-Y",$row->requested_date); ?>" required/>

</td>
</tr>
<td>
<label>
Response/Outcome from attempt to contact through phone
</label>
</td>
<td>
<textarea class="form-control" name="commentsphone"></textarea>
</td>

<tr>
<td>
<label>Date of contact via email</label>
</td>
<td>
<div class="date" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" data-date-viewmode="years">
<input placeholder="Date of contact via email" class=" m-wrap col-md-8 form-control " id="enddttt" type="text" name="dateofcontactviaemail" value="<?php if($row->requested_date!='') echo date("d-m-Y",$row->requested_date); ?>" required/>
</td>
</tr>
<td>
<label>
Response/Outcome from attempt to contact through email
</label>
</td>
<td>
<textarea class="form-control" name="commentsemail"></textarea>
</td>

<tr>

 



            <label>Image : </label>                     
            <input type="file" multiple="" name="images[]">                                 

           

 </tr>

</tr>


</table>

</div><!-- /.box-body -->
<div class="box-footer">
<?php

echo form_hidden('action',$action);
echo form_hidden('id',$id);
?>
<!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" name="withdraw" style="margin:0px 10px" value="withdrawn">Withdraw Resignation</button>-->
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" value="upload" style="margin:0px 10px">Submit</button>
</div><!-- /.box-footer -->
</form>
```

My controller methods are:

```html
private function upload_files($path, $title, $files)
    {


        $config = array(
             'upload_path'   => './uploads/',
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|gif|png',
            'overwrite'     => 1,                       
        );

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $images = array();

        foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $image) {
            $_FILES['images[]']['name']= $files['name'][$key];
            $_FILES['images[]']['type']= $files['type'][$key];
            $_FILES['images[]']['tmp_name']= $files['tmp_name'][$key];
            $_FILES['images[]']['error']= $files['error'][$key];
            $_FILES['images[]']['size']= $files['size'][$key];

            $fileName = $title .'_'. $image;

            $images[] = $fileName;

            $config['file_name'] = $fileName;

            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if ($this->upload->do_upload('images[]')) {
                $this->upload->data();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return $images;
    }

  function manager_add_absconding(){
   
   
   
   global $SITE,$USER;
   $data = array();
   $data['row'] = new stdClass();
   $data['row'] = $this->admin_init_elements->set_post_vals($this->input->post());
   $data['offices']=$this->mod_common->get_all_offices();
   $clients = currentuserclients();
   $data['roles'] = $this->mod_common->get_cat_array('designation','status',"1' AND id > '0",'designation');
   
    $data['reasons'] = $this->exit_common->get_all_reasons();
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
   
  

   
   
   //$data['roles'] = $this->exit_common->get_cat_array('designation','status',"1' AND id > '0",'designation');
   get_city_state_country_array($data,array('cityid'=>$data['row']->cityid));
   $data['error_message'] = '';
   $data['row']->id = $this->uri->segment(3);
   $data['id'] = $this->uri->segment(3);   
   $data['action'] = 'add';
   $data['heading'] = 'Add';   
   $data['msg_class'] = 'sukses';
   $data['path']=$path;  
   $post_action = $this->input->post('action');
   if($post_action=='add' || $post_action =='update' ){
    $post_array = $this->input->post();
    $action = ($post_action == 'add')?'inserted':'updated';
    //echo '<pre>';print_r($SITE);die;
     $post_array['exit_type'] = 'Employee Initiated';
     $data['managerid'] = $this->exit_common->get_managerids($id);
     $data['error_message'] = $this->exit_common->add_new_absconding_alert($post_array,$action);
     
       
     if($data['error_message'] == 'Record '.$action.' successfully'){
      $data['row'] = new stdClass();
      $data['row']->id = $this->uri->segment(3); 
      $data['row']->status = 1;
      
     }
    
   }
   $data['grievance_types'] = $this->mod_common->get_user_allowed_leaves();
   if($data['row']->id>0){
    $data['action'] = 'update';
    $data['heading'] = 'Edit';
    $data['rows'] = $this->mod_common->get_leave_request($data['row']->id);
    $clid = $data['row']->id; 
    $data['row']->id = $clid;
   }
   //$data['my_detail'] = $this->mod_common->get_my_details($USER->id);
   $data['my_detail'] = $this->exit_common->get_details_profile($USER->id,'users_details','userid'); 
   $data['my_detail']->userdetail = $this->exit_common->get_details($USER->id,'users');
   get_address($data['my_detail'],ADDRESS_TYPE1,$USER->id);
   $data['cities']=$this->exit_common->get_array_frontend('city');
   $data['notice_period']=$this->exit_common->get_notice_period($USER);
  
     if (!empty($_FILES['images']['name'][0])) {

                if ($this->upload_files($title, $_FILES['images']) === FALSE) {
                    $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>');
                }
            }                   

   $data['groups'] = $this->exit_common->get_all_names_by_user($USER);

   $this->data['maincontent'] = $this->load->view('maincontents/manager_add_new_exit', $data,true);

   $this->load->view('layout', $this->data);
    
   
  
 
  }
```

Comment: lots of mistake in your code

Comment: please let me know i can correct them. please suggest a simple way to do this

Comment: https://arjunphp.com/multiple-image-uploading-using-single-input-codeigniter/   please refer this link